# Azure Devops Pipeline won't build with fresh project (Docker - Linux)

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Azure Devops for an API project in NET 7, but I'm getting build error everytime, even with a fresh project with the base example of WeatherForecast.
I tried with Docker Windows, and downgrading the version of NET using NET 6, but it won't work either.

I tried with different accounts so it's not an auth problem, not even a version of NET problem, I think that is generating the yaml file in the incorrect way, this is the version of the NET 6 with Docker Linux:

```
trigger:

- master

resources:

- repo: self

variables:

dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '3cdd4a4c-****-****-****-132c5f7c77c0'
imageRepository: '****'
containerRegistry: 'directiocontainers.azurecr.io'
dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Test3Pipeline/Dockerfile'
tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:

- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
    vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
      command: buildAndPush
      repository: $(imageRepository)
      dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
      containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
      tags: |
      $(tag)
```

Comment: Please provide the error that you're getting.

Comment: Please add the variable `system.debug` and set the value to `true` in your pipeline. After that trigger a new pipeline to capture and share the complete debug logs of the error message.

Comment: It's critical to provide *all* of the relevant debugging information, including **the specific error message you're receiving**. Saying "I get a build error" is like going to the doctor and saying "I don't feel well".

Comment: I posted as an answer the error.
I tried to post in the main post that piece but it wouldn't stop to tell me that had no indentation, the problem wasn't present in the answer.
Sorry for the misscomunication.
Now you know the answer or you just go around correcting posts?

Comment: To narrow down the issue, it's suggested that you could build your project locally. If it's successful, set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine to run the pipeline. If it failed, check and edit your project to ensure it can be built.

Answer (score 0):

```
That's the part that I think talks about the error:

##[error] > [build 3/7] COPY [Test3Pipeline/Test3Pipeline.csproj, Test3Pipeline/]:
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;] > [build 3/7] COPY [Test3Pipeline/Test3Pipeline.csproj, Test3Pipeline/]:
##[error]------
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]------
##[error]Dockerfile:10
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Dockerfile:10
##[error]--------------------
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]--------------------
##[error]   8 |     FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]   8 |     FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
##[error]   9 |     WORKDIR /src
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]   9 |     WORKDIR /src
##[error]  10 | >>> COPY ["Test3Pipeline/Test3Pipeline.csproj", "Test3Pipeline/"]
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]  10 | >>> COPY ["Test3Pipeline/Test3Pipeline.csproj", "Test3Pipeline/"]
##[error]  11 |     RUN dotnet restore "Test3Pipeline/Test3Pipeline.csproj"
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]  11 |     RUN dotnet restore "Test3Pipeline/Test3Pipeline.csproj"
##[error]  12 |     COPY . .
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]  12 |     COPY . .
##[error]--------------------
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]--------------------
##[error]ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref b3f67a6d-0f36-4371-8431-22933491e334::nknpqivautqy7baur4gwjtpwl: "/Test3Pipeline/Test3Pipeline.csproj": not found
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref b3f67a6d-0f36-4371-8431-22933491e334::nknpqivautqy7baur4gwjtpwl: "/Test3Pipeline/Test3Pipeline.csproj": not found
##[debug]Trying to logout from registry: ***
##[debug]DOCKER_CONFIG=/home/vsts/work/_temp/DockerConfig_1697038045208
##[debug]agent.tempDirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp
##[debug]Found the Docker Config stored in the temp path. Docker config path: /home/vsts/work/_temp/DockerConfig_1697038045208/config.json, Docker config: {"auths": { "***": {"auth": "***", "email": "ServicePrincipal@AzureRM" } }, "HttpHeaders":{"X-Meta-Source-Client":"VSTS"} }
##[debug]Deleting Docker config directory. Path: /home/vsts/work/_temp/DockerConfig_1697038045208/config.json
##[debug]DOCKER_CONFIG=/home/vsts/work/_temp/DockerConfig_1697038045208
##[debug]agent.tempDirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp
##[debug]Deleting Docker config directory. Path: /home/vsts/work/_temp/DockerConfig_1697038045208
##[debug]set DOCKER_CONFIG=
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=DOCKER_CONFIG;isOutput=false;issecret=false;]
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your build context is incorrect, try adding

`buildContext: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)`

right under the

`containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)`

line of your yml pipeline file.

Comment: I tried and the error is still the same, if you want I can copy it to you but it seems identical to me.

Comment: Unfortunately the log you posted is missing important informations such as `##[debug]buildContext=XXXXXXXX` and `##[debug]SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY=XXXXXXXX` lines

Comment: 2023-10-25T15:04:47.8606980Z ##[debug]buildContext=/home/vsts/work/1/s/**
2023-10-25T15:04:47.8607572Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work/1/s